# How to enforce referential integrity in RedShift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

RedShift doesn't support enforcing any constraints. Say that I had the following setup:

> Movie(mID, title)
>
> Rating(rID, mID, comment)

It wouldn't make sense to have a rating that didn't have a movie associated with the rating. But RedShift doesn't support enforcing any constraints!

Say that I had a broken database system with Ratings and no movies attached. How should be dealt with?

For example: **Is it common to have periodic clean ups?**

Comment: I'd say rather than cleaning up you should detect and fix the bug.

Comment: I agree, but this is a hypothetical situation - that might happen if a junior developer joined our team. This is also very likely to occur.

Comment: This is also incredibly likely. I'm surprised that I couldn't find a quick answer online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support constraints by design.

In the typical use case for Redshift, i.e. BI / Analytics, data would be cleaned before being made visible to the end user (an analyst or dashboard-ing app). **The clean up step is an important part of the data pipeline**. This clean up can happen before data is loaded into the database, *a traditional ETL approach*, or cleaned up after loading into the database, *a more recent ELT approach*, or the clean up can happen both before & after the data is loaded *(I guess you'd call that ETLT, although that's a mouthful)*

The cleanup is usually done as the data is loaded, however with more frequent data loads (e.g. near real time click streams), the cleanup & aggregation queries are often periodic & less frequent than the data loads, so analysts and dashboards can update some real time metrics, while others refresh hourly.

#### For this particular case

You can tell all analysts to use an `INNER JOIN` or add `Rating.mID IS NOT NULL` in each query. This is the quickest approach.

Or you can run this script periodically to expose only the cleaned data to the end user.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RatingCleaned;
CREATE TABLE RatingCleanded AS 
SELECT * 
FROM Rating 
WHERE mID IS NOT NULL;
```

Or, create the cleaned table once, and populate it incrementally.

```
-- create once
CREATE TABLE RatingCleanded AS 
SELECT * 
FROM Rating 
WHERE mID IS NOT NULL;

-- populate incrementally
INSERT INTO RatingCleaned
SELECT Rating.*
FROM Rating
LEFT JOIN RatingCleaned ON Rating.rID = RatingCleaned.rID
WHERE RatingCleaned.rID IS NULL
  AND Rating.mID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hey Haleemur: Such a great answer. Thanks for letting me know! It's strange to me that we have to do periodic clean ups - but I guess I'm new to the area.